# Interior of a set properties

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I had a basic doubt in proving the following theorem:

Prove or disprove $ \operatorname{Int}(A) \cup \operatorname{Int}(B) = \operatorname{Int}(A \cup B) $ where $ A \subset \mathbb{R}\; and \;B \subset \mathbb{R} $

*So I chose $x \in \operatorname{Int}(A) \cup \operatorname{Int}(B)$, therefore  $x \in \operatorname{Int}(A)$ or $x \in \operatorname{Int}(B)$.*

*Now  $\forall \;y \in N(x,\epsilon)$, we have $y \in A$ or $y \in B$ as, according to $x\in \operatorname{Int}(A)$ or $x \in \operatorname{Int}(B)$.  Therefore $y \in A \cup B$. Hence $N(x,\epsilon) \subset A \cup B$. Therefore we proved that $x\in \operatorname{Int}(A\cup B)$. Since we  choose arbitrary element from $\operatorname{Int}(A)\cup \operatorname{Int}(B)$, we have proved that $\operatorname{Int}(A)\cup \operatorname{Int}(B)\subset\operatorname{Int}(A\cup B)$.*

But I was stuck in the second part when I proceeded the same way. I want to be sure if my first part is correct and how to approach the second half of it.

Comment: `$` signs aren't really for writing in italics. Try putting `*` before and after text to make it italic. For example `Writing $x \in A$ *emphatically*` produces "Writing $x \in A$ *emphatically*".

Comment: Thanks. I didn't intend to write in italics, just I had to use math symbols in that paragraph that's why I used $ symbol

Comment: In that case, use single \$ signs, rather than double \$\$ signs. That gives you inline mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Take $A=\mathbb{Q}$, $B=\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. Then $\mathrm{Int}(A)=\mathrm{Int}(B)=\emptyset$, and $\mathrm{Int}(A\cup B)=\mathbb R$.

Your proof of inclusion in one direction is correct, but you rightly had trouble with the other direction because it does not hold!